# Is there a way to find a pictureBox from many

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 9 Pictures Boxes. If I click one Box it should change the Label to something like :

```
label_selectedcar = "Selected Car : " + 'ImageName'
```

I did create the Same Click Event for all of the PictureBoxes.

```
private void SelectCar(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    }
```

How can i get the Image Name from the PictureBox that i clicked on. The Images all have the car name in it.

[image: Form]

Comment: The name of the image/file is lost after assigning it to the pbox.Image. So you need to store it. The Tag property is a common way to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store userdata in the `PictureBox.Tag` property then use it like this

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;

    MessageBox.Show(pictureBox.Tag.ToString());
}
```

You could store the "ImageName" inside the tag